# Iterators product on array of arrays

Tags: julia

How can I create an iterator on the product of arrays, from an array of arrays?
The Array size not predetermined.

Basically the following works as I wish:

```
for i in Base.Iterators.product([1,2,3],[4,5])
   print(i)
end
(1, 4)(2, 4)(3, 4)(1, 5)(2, 5)(3, 5)
```

But I would like it to work for an array of arrays, but I am getting different result:

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5]]
for i in Base.Iterators.product(x)
   print(i)
end
([1, 2, 3],)([4, 5],)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [splat operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#...) to interpolate the array of arrays into the function call:

```
julia> x = [[1,2,3],[4,5]];

julia> for i in Base.Iterators.product(x...)
          print(i)
       end
(1, 4)(2, 4)(3, 4)(1, 5)(2, 5)(3, 5)
```